# WorkManager NetworkType.CONNECTED constraint met even if I disabled internet connectivity, while using VPN apps causing unexpected retry scheduling

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager, flutter-workmanager

VPN applications seem to break WorkManager's NetworkType.CONNECTED constraint in my app. Because I have set setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED) of work manager request  explicitly. However, when I'm using VPN apps and turn off the internet, Retry will be scheduled, and keeps on running even when internet is turned off. Normally, due to the NetworkType.CONNECTED constraint, it shouldn't run if internet is turned off. A bug from WorkManager or it's how supposed to be with VPN apps?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that's weird, but I think I got it ;

I think this is the normal behavior of the WorkManager in this case because when VPN starts in your device, it creates a virtual private network connection (obviously), which routes all network traffic through a secure server.

Which **may provide** the impression that the device is online even if the actual network connection (such as Wi-Fi or cellular data) is not active. As a result, even though the physical network connection is disabled, the VPN connection may still satisfy WorkManager's `NetworkType.CONNECTED` constraint.

In other words, if you disable internet access while a VPN is active, WorkManager may still regard the VPN connection as "connected" and may continue to retry tasks that have a `NetworkType.CONNECTED`.

Comment: Thanks but, NetworkType.CONNECTED value should be computed to true based on true internet connectivity for the WorkManager api to work as expected in different edge cases, right?

Comment: Not necessarily true, if there is any network connection, it will be true, here the what the documentation is saying: Any working network connection is required for this work.

Comment: Yeah, any working network connection is misleading and will cause inconsistent behaviour was my point. I understand how it is right now, but i'm still against the implementation of NetowrkType.Connected.

Comment: Yeah that's the normal behavior, lot of Apis are like that, they will tell you that you are connected to a Network, but not necessarily have internet connection, you have to check it manually, ping some 8.8.8.8 to see yourself! Hope the answer was beneficial to you!